# Estilar un pseudoelemento ::after con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

¿Cómo seleccionar desde jQuery un elemento de este estilo?

`.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2)::after { }`

La idea es poder modificar ciertas reglas `CSS` desde JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde javascript es **imposible** dar estilo a las [pseudoclases](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes) y a los [pseudoelementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudoelementos) porque estas reglas no son parte del DOM.

Para solventar dicha limitación tienes varias opciones

**Agregar especificidad**

Agregas una clase a tu hoja de estilos, ej `.clase1`

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('clase1');
  });
});
```

```css
.page-container .single-page::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  background-color: violet;
}
.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2).clase1::after {
  background-color: blue;
}
.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2).clase2::after {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="single-page"></div>
  <div class="single-page"></div>
  <div class="single-page"></div>
  <div class="single-page"></div>
  <button type="button">Haz click</button>
</div>
```

Al tener más especificidad tendrá mayor prioridad y por tanto mostrará el estilo deseado. La desventaja es que la cantidad de modificaciones que puedes hacer desde javascript está limitada por la cantidad de clases que generes, es decir, este método es viable cuando las modificaciones sean *discretas* y no para hacer modificaciones *arbitrarias*.

Puedes usar también selectores de atributos y elementos como medio para agregar especificidad.

**Reemplazo**

Puedes reemplazar los pseudoelementos por elementos y estos si permiten ser manipulados

```
.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2) .after { 
    //estilos
}
```

Técnicamente los pseudo elementos [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::before) y [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after) son el primero y último descendiente directo de un elemento dado y tu puedes crear un elemento que ocupe la misma posición y estilarlo

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="single-page">
        <span class="before"></span>
        <div class="contenido"></div>
        <span class="after"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto es un truco muy sucio por la cantidad de elementos que deberás generar y por supuesto tiene sus limitaciones como que es muy complejo reproducir todos los pseudoelementos como [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter), [`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line), etc, pero te permitirá agregar cualquier estilo *arbitrario* mediante javascript.

Si lo usas de esta forma puedes usar los selectores [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) y [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) para seleccionar los pseudoelementos "simulados".

Para simular pseudoclases puedes usar eventos como [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) y [`mousemove`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) que también solventarán en parte el problema.

Chequea el ejemplo

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var color = $('#color').val();
    $('.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2) :last-child').css({
      'background-color': color
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.page-container .single-page .after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Escriba un color</label>
  <input id="color" type="text">
  <button type="button">Cambiar</button>
</div>
<small>Ej blue, orange, #00f0e1</small>
<div class="page-container">

  <div class="single-page">
    <span class="after"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="single-page">
    <span class="after"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="single-page">
    <span class="after"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="single-page">
    <span class="after"></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, en el caso de agregar especificidad, agrego una clase a la hoja de estilos, pero no serviría para nada para seleccionar el elemento desde jQuery, no?

Comment: @oscarvady Exacto, deberías tener los estilos agregados al documento y **si** lo debes seleccionar para poder agregar la clase deseada.

Comment: En mi caso particular, me gustaría modificar una regla `CSS` del pseudoelemento, pero solo lo podría hacer desde JavaScript, que es donde conozco el valor a aplicar. En concreto, es el nombre de una imagen para poner de background, lo cual podría ser cualquier cosa (carga dinámica). Me temo que solo me queda la opción de Reemplazo.

Comment: @oscarvady Si es así como dices, reemplazar los pseudoelementos es la única opción. Yo usé este truco una vez para hacer una vista previa de un conjunto de estilos **ya generados** y el usuario en teoría podía escoger cualquier estilo que quisiera y escoger cualquier imagen. En tu caso puedes desechar el uso de pseudoelementos que es básicamente lo que dice la técnica de reemplazo.

Comment: @blonfu Disculpa la confusión. En realidad debería decir "Desde javascript es imposible..." No me percaté de que como se leía era un error. Por supuesto que desde CSS es posible. Editada la respuesta.

Comment: @devconcept ah vale, era una confusión. Veo que lo has corregido, borro mi comentario entonces

Answer (score 2):

Al ser `::after` un pseudoelemento y no existir en el DOM, es practicamente imposible usar directamente ese selector en jQuery.

Una solución típica a este problema es jugar con las clases (agregar o quitar según lo que se quiera hacer):

```js
$('button.click1').click(function() {
  $('.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('click1').removeClass('click2');
});

$('button.click2').click(function() {
  $('.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('click2').removeClass('click1');
});
```

```css
.page-container .single-page:nth-of-type(2)::after {
   content: 'Adios';  
}

.page-container .single-page.click1:nth-of-type(2)::after {
   background-color: blue;
   color: white;
}

.page-container .single-page.click2:nth-of-type(2)::after {
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="single-page">
    Hola
  </div>
  <div class="single-page">
    me fui 
  </div>
</div>
<button class="click1">Fondo azul</button>
<button class="click2">Fondo rojo</button>
```